# How to create function Blocks in StackExchange questions?

Tags: support, asking-questions

As a French student living in the US, I'm using both QWERTY and AZERTY keyboards.

tex.stackexhange is a good website, but a problem comes when it's about asking questions.

Indeed, when I wanna use the `` ` `` as in `subcaption`, I have to switch my keyboard to a US keyboard cause that character doesn't exist on the French one. 
The same problems comes with other functions too.

Is there another way to implement that function in a question without switching keyboards ? Does a universal/international code exist for that ?

Comment: Have you seen [How do I mark inline code?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863)? Instead of typing `\``, you can press Ctrl+K or click the "code" button with "{ }" on it. Or use HTML: `<code>foo bar</code>`. I don’t think Stack Exchange is likely to change their markup system since it’s heavily based on [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax), a very simple markup language. That also is where the backtick markup comes from.

Comment: Related: [Wikipedia: AZERTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY#Grave_accent) which supports [Lionel MANSUY’s answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3277/16595). Maybe you need to hit the space bar or a non-grave-ed-able letter (neither a, e, o, i nor u) as ` can be a dead key.

Answer (score 5):

On my French keyboard layout (on a Mac), the \ key is mapped to the ` character.  Are you sure that your keyboard layout doesn't provide the character at all?

**Evidence:** (please don't correct the typos).

This line zqs typed on q French keyboqrd lqyoyt: `this pqrt` is so,e inline code:

(This line was typed on a French keyboard layout. `this part` is some inline code.)

[image: French keyboard layout]

Answer (score 1):

On a french PC keyboard this symbol is accessible through `AltGr + è` (or the `7` key if you prefer...), and typing a space or a `\`.